# What did the note state in House Of The Disappeared?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-the-disappeared

In the Korean movie *House Of The Disappeared*, Hyo-je hands his mother a note.

We later learn that Old Mi-Hee gives Hyo-je the note.

What does the note read?

I watched the Venezuelan Original - *The House At The End Of Time*, they don't say what's in it in that film either.

The detail here appears critical but the subs don't translate.

Here's the snap of the note:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

이 집에서 나가 아빠가 아이를 죽일거야

Translates roughly to:
"leave this house, dad's gonna kill the kid"